# Move Debug As > JUnit Test in Eclipse to the root of the context menu

Tags: eclipse, junit

How do you move the Debug As > JUnit Test in Eclipse to the root of the context menu?  I've gotten used to the IntelliJ context menu where the Debug is listed at the root.  This is when I've selected a single test method.

For example, in Eclipse:

[image]

In IntelliJ:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The general order of menu items is defined fixed by the plugin providing or extending the context menu. There is no configuration.

Maybe the [EclipseRunnerPlugin](https://code.google.com/p/eclipserunnerplugin/) could be of help for you. It allows to have launch configurations be sorted and grouped in a separate view.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I switched to keyboard shortcuts.  Cmd-F11.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible. Because all you see in Eclipse are essentially plugins. Your goal cannot be achieved unless you modify the Eclipse plugin or make your own plugin.